# How to share a Rails model with other Devise users in read-only mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many, cancancan

In a Rails 5 application, I have a `shortlist` model in a HABTM relationship with a `user` model, with the users controlled by Devise. This is all working as expected, where each User can see their own Shortlists (only).

```
class Shortlist < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
 ...

class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_and_belongs_to_many :shortlists
  ...

class ShortlistsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @shortlists = current_user.shortlists
    ...
```

Now I wish to allow users to "share" shortlists with other users, who will have read-only access to the shared shortlists.

I could add the second user to the shortlist (`@shortlist.users << User.second`) but this would give them full read-write access.

The [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) gem looks promising, but I'm not sure how to configure the abilities, to allow User1 full control over their shortlists, and to give User2 read-only access to shortlists that User1 shares with them.

How can I restrict the second user to having read-only access?

Comment: CanCanCan seems promising until you get to the point when you have to do something even slightly complex and its stupid DSL gets in your way. I changed all my apps over to Pundit years ago. Its a bit harder to get your head around initially but its just plain old OOP and deals with complexity much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution in adding a `owner_id` column to the shortlists table is actually a good one as it lets you efficiently eager load the association and is a lot less cumbersome to deal with.

If you wanted to keep track of the user which creates the record too through a join table thats possible through a roles system but it would be a lot more clunky. The Rolify gem is one such as example of a generic roles system.

One thing you should do is use `has_many through:` instead of [the near useless `has_and_belongs_to_many`](https://www.seancdavis.com/blog/why-i-dont-use-has-and-belongs-to-many-in-rails/):

```
class Shortlist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, 
    class_name: 'User'
  has_many :shares
end

# rails g model user:belongs_to shortlist:belongs_to
class Share < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :shortlist
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :shortlists, 
    foreign_key: :owner_id
  has_many :shares
  has_many :lists_shared_with_me,
    through: :shares,
    source: :shortlists 
end
```

This lets you add additional columns to the table like for example flags that will let you grant other users the rights to edit the shortlist or an automatic expiry date. You could also generate unique URLs for each share to keep track of which "share" is being used. None of that is possible with HABTM.

Comment: Many thanks Max. I actually did make the switch to a `has_many through:` association but I omitted that from my answer as it didn't really affect the outcome.

Comment: The rest of the question would be a bit too long to answer. You should ideally use a authorization library like Pundit or CanCanCan. If not you should use something like `raise AuthorizationError unless @shortlist.owner == current_user` to bail out of your method. You then handle the exception with rescue from. The reason you want to use an exception to bail out is to halt the exection immediately and break the chain of any callbacks added to the controller which could have side effects.

Comment: Cool, I'll look into that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I added an `owner` flag on the shortlists, which is calculated to `current_user.id` when the shortlist is created. This allows me to distinguish between the owner and viewers.

Before saving a shortlist I check whether `@shortlist.owner == current_user.id` and show an error message if not.

This works well enough but I'd be keen to hear if there's a method that's less hacky.